# Azure pipeline not running - properties parameter null

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

In Azure Data Factory I am using the **Copy functionality** with a **Linked Service**. In the Linked Service I am using **REST** and I created two parameters to be able to put dynamic content to the url.

Unfortunately after creating that the pipeline does not run properly and the exception is very general: **Operation on target (PIPELINE'S NAME) failed: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: properties.**

Which properties is meant here? I was trying to overwrite it in the pipeline, but it wouldn't be recognized while running the pipeline. 
I am struggling with this problem for hours, is it maybe just the wrong way to make dynamic contents for the REST urls? Does anyone have experience with that? I will be very grateful, thanks! :)

Comment: What are the two parameters you created?

Comment: It's an array with country list and a token for the api_connection